# Visa checkout multiple transactions

Tags: javascript, visa-api

I am working with `VISA CHECKOUT API` and i am trying to make it work with multiple products at once . The problem is that i want the money payed for this products to be delivered to 2 different persons. For example i buy a phone that costs `20$` and i want ro send this money to a person. The shipping is `3$` and i want to send this money to another person. How can i do it? I am working in `javascript` and i read the docs but i didn't find anything.

Comment: How are we suppose to know anything about this based on the information provided?

Comment: @MrZach  What do you need to know. You don't need to know something about my scripts to answer this question. Imagine you have your ebook site. And i am the user. I choose visa payment option and i need to pay the shipping and the book to 2 different persons. How would you do this? What do you need to use to acomplish this?

Comment: @user8708554 Hi! So, did you find any solutions so far?